# How to prevent labels from overlapping arrows in diagrams' Edge() - class

Tags: python, python-3.x, overlap, diagram

While using the [diagrams as code Python library](https://diagrams.mingrammer.com/docs/guides/edge), how can I prevent text from overlapping arrows as seen in the screenshot?

[image: overlapping-arrows]

```
from diagrams import Cluster, Diagram, Edge
...

with Diagram("Clustered Web Services",
             show=False,
             graph_attr={
                 'pad': '0.1',
                 'bgcolor': 'transparent'
             }) as diag:

    ...
    
    with Cluster("AWS"):
        with Cluster("Pipeline"):
            ....

        with Cluster("S3 Storage"):
            ...
    # PLOT
    ...
    lambda_main >> Edge(label="Storing filtered & prioritized suggestions",
                        style="bold",
                        color="black") >> s3_bucket_full
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that in many cases, using **xlabel** instead of just **label** within **Edge(..)** helps resolving the issue.